Protocol-Kit not fetching v1.3.0 contracts
Safe contracts v1.3.0 and v1.4.1 are deployed and added to safe-deployments (they are part of the latest release) but they're not being picked up by Protocol-kit when I do
  const safeProvider = new SafeProvider({
    provider: "https://skopje-rpc.gptprotocol.io",
    signer: PRIVATE_KEY_SIGNER,
  });
  const proxyContract = await getProxyFactoryContract({ safeProvider, safeVersion: '1.3.0' });

I get the error
Error: Invalid safeProxyFactory contract address

This error doesn't appear when I use safe-version as 1.4.1 (Since that version of contract was part of previous release)

The Safe{Core} SDK does not yet support Skopje network. For the SDK to support it you can deploy the contracts on this network and open a pull request on the deployments repository so they can be added to the list of officially supported networks.
Hope it helps; Best, Louis

Thanks for the response @Louis
But we've deployed the contracts for both v1.3.0 and v1.4.1
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/pull/756
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/pull/717
And the same happens for our chain's mainnet
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/pull/755
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/pull/757

Right, thanks for that! The problem should be solved when the next version of the SDK is released, which will pick up the latest deployments. I cannot give you an exact date when this will happen but it should not take more than a couple of weeks. Please hang tight in the meantime
